# jQuery custom event sequence

Tags: jquery, sequence, custom-events

I'm creating a custom JS object. This object performs some `action`.
I want to be able to notify consumer of the object (by triggering custom events) that `action` will be performed **and** `action` is already performed. (This model of behavior is known in ASP.NET where controls have `onBeforeAction` and `onAfterAction` events).
The tricky part is that I would like consumer to be able to stop/interrupt the event sequence.

Here is an algorithm (in Human#) of desired behaviour:

```
this.trigger('onBeforeAction');
if (!onBeforeAction.wasCanceled){
  this.doAction();
  this.trigger('onAfterAction');
}
```

Having this functionality in my object would allow consumer to do something like this:

```
$(myIntance).bind('onBeforeAction', function(){
  if (!someCondition.satisfied)
    return false;
  return true;
});
$(myIntance).bind('onAfterAction', function(){
  // respond to action here
});
```

Any ideas on how to implement a 'controllable' event sequence would be great.
Thanks in advance.
// R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have found solution.
Here's what I came up with:

```
// my object
function Car(){
    this.currentSpeed = 0;
}

Car.prototype.goFaster = function(){
    var event = $.Event('beforeSpeedIncrease'); 
    $(this).trigger(event); // notify "onBeforeAction"
    if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()){
        this.currentSpeed += 10; // actual action
        $(this).trigger('afterSpeedIncreased'); // notify "onAfterAction"
    }
}
```

Then some consumer could act like this:

```
var speedLimit = 30;

var carUnderControl = new Car();

$(carUnderControl)
    .bind('beforeSpeedIncrease', function(e){
        if (carUnderControl.currentSpeed >= speedLimit){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Speed increase prevented, current speed: ' + carUnderControl.currentSpeed);
        }
    })
    .bind('afterSpeedIncreased', function(){
        console.log('Current speed: ' + carUnderControl.currentSpeed);
    });
```

I've run this in FireFox with Firebug (of course). Executing  `carUnderControl.goFaster();` from Firebug's console for three times showed *Current speed: ...* message three times. Subsequent executions of `goFaster()` method showed *Speed increase prevented* message.

That's the functionality I wanted to achieve.
Any recommendations how to improve this are very much welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
  var origin = $.fn.click;
  $.fn.click = function(event) {
    //before function 
     origin.call(this, event);
     //after function 
     // remember to use return as this could help with jq chainability 
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Replace click with your custom event name :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how my object will be notified that onBeforeAction handler returned false and it should not raise subsequent onAfterAction event? Sorry, but I just don't see the whole picture